# find certain string in string

Tags: python

well as title says
i was given a task to find the word Hello in any shape in given string that means its not just hello but i will have to find Hellllloooooo or heeeelllloooo also
what ive wrote so far is this but i know its not 100% percent working
i need my code to give 'yes' if there is a Hello in any shape and 'no' if there is no hellos like Heleo or Heeelooo

```
x = input()
answer = []
for i in range(0, len (x)):
y = x.find('h')
answer.extend(x[y])
x = x[y+1:]
i = y
if len(answer) == 5 or len(x) < 5:
    break
y = x.find('e')
answer.extend(x[y])
x = x[y+1:]
i = y
if len(answer) == 5 or len(x) < 5:
    break
y = x.find('l')
answer.extend(x[y])
x = x[y+1:]
i = y
if len(answer) == 5 or len(x) < 5:
    break
y = x.find('l')
answer.extend(x[y])
x = x[y+1:]
i = y
if len(answer) == 5 or len(x) < 5:
    break
y = x.find('o')
answer.extend(x[y])
x = x[y+1:]
i = y
if len(answer) == 5 or len(x) < 5:
    break
if answer == ['h','e','l','l','o']:
    print ('YES')
else:
    print('NO')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try solving the problem by patter matching the input string by using regular expression. Basic example for your case:

```
import re


input_str = input().lower()
pattern = re.compile(r'^h+e+l{2,}o+$')

if pattern.match(input_str):
    print('YES')
else:
    print('NO')
```

Answer (score 0):

You can solve this simply like this:

```
user_inp = input().lower()

if 'hello' in user_inp:
    print('yes')
else:
    print('No')
```

The 'in' will check even if the string is present at any position.

Comment: `'hello' in 'hhhheeeelllloooo'` is `False`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `collections.Counter()` in combination with `set()` to create conditions that will meet the criteria for a word to be `'hello'`

```
from collections import Counter
words = ['hello', 'Hello', 'hhhhhhello', 'hellllllo', 'HHEEELLLllllooO', 'HHHHHHELLOOOOOO']

for word in words:
    x = word.lower()
    if all(Counter(x)[i] > 0 for i in Counter(x)) and Counter(x)['l'] > 1:
        if all(i in 'helo' for i in set(x)):
            print(word)
```